# Distributed sort and pagination

Tags: postgresql, algorithm, spring-boot, distributed

I have 2 microservices with isolated databases. I have one entity (table) per microservice in relation one to one. I need pagination on UI with all fields from both entities and sorting by any fields.
Any idea how to od it?

Comment: Broken by design.

Comment: I had two isolated systems, but right now I need to merge systems and show results on UI.